# ConcurrentModificationException during iteration through collection

Tags: java, stream, spring-batch, concurrentmodification

I'm iterating through a list in my ItemProcessor in spring-batch app and I'm getting this error:

```
java.util.ConcurrentModificationException: null
```

When I set my batch config to use a single thread it works fine. I'm using SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor. Customer is an entity and it has a list of CustomerAlias.

```
private void fillCustomer(final Customer customer, final ExtractLine result){

CustomerAlias customerAlias = customer.getCustomerAlias().stream().filter(s -> s.getAliasType().isAster()).findFirst().orElse(nullAlias);
result.setCustomer(customerAlias.getCalNmeAliasName());
}


java.util.ConcurrentModificationException: null
at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.checkForComodification(ArrayList.java:901)
at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(ArrayList.java:851)
at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection$IteratorProxy.next(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:815)
at java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.tryAdvance(Spliterators.java:1812)
at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachWithCancel(ReferencePipeline.java:126)
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel(AbstractPipeline.java:498)
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:485)
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)
at java.util.stream.FindOps$FindOp.evaluateSequential(FindOps.java:152)
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.findFirst(ReferencePipeline.java:464)
at com.liq.sub.impl.MyProcessor.fillCustomer(MyProcessor.java:107)
```

Comment: Are you trying to modify your list in your threads while iterating over it?

Comment: No, I'm not. I'm just reading it.

Answer (score 5):

> When I set my batch config to use a single thread it works fine.

Then the answer is pretty simple: some other thread is currently iterating that collection.

Now you need to step back and identify where in your source code that collection might be modified while this code is running.

There is no "magic" in place that would help avoiding that.

Comment: Fixed problem by synchronizing this method

Comment: @ElBlokko Just for the record: this means you found a quick shortcut. You are*suppressing* the problem. It might still be worth a bit of time to **understand** what is happening. You see, that little keyword *synchronized* **might** lead to performance impacts. Code that could run in parallel before ... will not any more. Maybe that is good, but maybe it has *other* consequences. So, I am glad you found a workaround, but please understand that a working around a problem isn't at all the same as *solving* the problem.